# parse lines without subshell ... how?

Tags: bash

i need to parse a number of lines without entering a subshell

```
cat << EOF | while read -r cmd
sleep 100
sleep 110
sleep 120
EOF

do
    echo $cmd
done
```

will result:

```
sleep 100
sleep 110
sleep 120
```

and it is working, but problem is i need the result outside subshell (be cause i need the results after), tried with for instead of while, but then it won't parse lines but words:

```
for cmd in `cat << EOF
sleep 100
sleep 110
sleep 120
EOF`

do
  echo $cmd
done
```

will result:

```
sleep
100
sleep
110
sleep
120
```

so, any ideea how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read -r cmd; do
   echo $cmd
done <<EOF
sleep 100
sleep 110
sleep 120
EOF
```

Pipes create a subshell.  I/O redirection (including here-documents) doesn't.

Comment: code looks a little ... kinky :P, but thank you ! it is working and get the job done ;)